# How to get value of a control which is in repeater item from dropdownlist's selecetedchanged event which in the same repeater item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>
         <%#Eval("Caption")%>
      </td>
      <td>
         <%#Eval("CreatedBy")%>
      </td>
      <td>
         <%#Eval("CreationDate")%>
      </td>
      <td>
         <%#Eval("Status")%>
      </td>
      <td class="center">
         <div class="controls center">
            <a href="NewsCommentEdit.aspx?mtid =<%#Eval("UserId")%>" title="Güncelle" class="tip">
               <span class="icon12 icomoon-icon-pencil"></span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnComment" Value='<%#Eval("NewsCommentId")%>' />
         <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStatus" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlStatus_Changed">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Onay Bekliyor" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Onaylandı" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Reddedildi" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
      </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I want to get hdnComment's value in ddlStatus's selected index changed event. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    protected void ddlStatus_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        string value;
        HiddenField comment = ((Control)sender).Parent.FindControl("hdnComment") as HiddenField;
        if (comment != null) 
        {
            value = comment.Value;
        }
    }
```